# SystemParametersInfoA Only Works Temporarily

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I am using `SystemParametersInfoA` to enable high contrast mode with `SPI_SETHIGHCONTRAST`, but every time I press the Windows key to bring up the search bar and type a single letter in, it all goes back to normal.

I tried passing both `SPI_SETHIGHCONTRAST`, `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE` and `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE`, but nothing worked.

I am using the latest Windows 10 version.

What is going on?

Comment: When it works "temporarily" do you see Aero being disabled?  Aero automatically gets disabled when Windows detects an incompatible app, and re-enables when you switch to a compatible app.  I suspect this is what is happening.

Comment: Yes it switches to a high contrast mode as if I would enable it trough settings and stays that way forever even between different processes up until I try to search something in the search bar.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem on windows 2004. I first use `SPI_GETHIGHCONTRAST` to get a `HIGHCONTRAST` struct and then add `HIGHCONTRAST.dwFlags |= HCF_HIGHCONTRASTON;` finnally, use `SPI_SETHIGHCONTRAST` + `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE| SPIF_SENDCHANGE`.

Comment: My Windows is not activated. Perhaps once I try to perform a search some other Windows Service notices I am not activated and shuts down my theme change.